# BASH: can grep on command line, but not in script

Tags: linux, bash, grep

Did this million times already, but this time it's not working
I try to grep "$TITLE" from a file. on command line it's working, "$TITLE" variable is not empty, but when i run the script it finds nothing

*title contains more than one word

```
echo "$TITLE"
cat PAGE.$TEMP.2 | grep "$TITLE"
```

what i've tried:

```
echo "cat PAGE.$TEMP.2 | grep $TITLE"
```

*to see if title is not empty and file name is actually there*

Comment: Have you actually tried to `grep` the file with the value? Maybe the title really isn't in the file.

Comment: yes i tried, it's there 100%. i even took the output of echo "cat PAGE.$TEMP.2 | grep $TITLE" and run it

Comment: But the first time you had quotes around the `"$TITLE"`, the second time you don't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure that `$TITLE` does not have leading or trailing whitespace which is not in the file?  Your fix with the string would strip out whitespace before execution, so it would not see it.

For example, with a file containing 'Line one':

```
/home/user1> TITLE=' one '
/home/user1> grep "$TITLE" text.txt
/home/user1> cat text.txt | grep $TITLE
Line one
```

Try `echo "<$TITLE>"`, or `echo "$TITLE"|od -xc` which sould enable you to spot errant chars.

Comment: WORKED! thanks man! od -xc helped me, great tool. i added tr -d '\r\n\' and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This command

```
echo "cat PAGE.$TEMP.2 | grep $TITLE"
```

echoes a string that starts with 'cat'. It does not run a command. You would want

```
echo "$( cat PAGE.$TEMP.2 | grep $TITLE )"
```

although that is identical in functionality to the simpler

```
cat PAGE.$TEMP.2 | grep $TITLE
```

And as pointed out by others, there is no need to pipe a single file using `cat`; `grep` can read from files just fine:

```
grep "$TITLE" "PAGE.$TEMP.2"
```

(Your default behavior should be to quote parameter expansions, unless you can show it is incorrect to do so.)

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
~> cat test.dat
abc
cda
xyz
~> export GRP=cda
~> cat test.dat | grep $GRP
cda
```

Edit:

Also the proper way to use `grep` is:

```
~> grep $GRP test.dat
```